# DB2: Column-Aliases with Line-Breaks

Tags: db2, alias, db2-9.7, dbeaver

Using DB2 9.7, is it possible to produce a result set where the column-headers contain line-breaks? Something like:

```
select field_name as "Line1<br>Line2" from table_name
```

I want the column-header to look like this:

```
Line1
Line2
```

However, this is not for HTML. Instead I'm wanting it to look this way when I run the query (raw) in my sql editor ([Dbeaver](http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/)) and in the CSV file I export from Dbeaver (so that the columns are narrower -- to prevent horizontal scrolling while viewing the result-set).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DB2 will allow you to use a new line character in a quoted identifier:

```
$ db2 'select ibmreqd "foo
> bar" from sysibm.sysdummy1'

foo
bar
-------
Y      

  1 record(s) selected.
```

The question is, will Dbeaver let you enter a new line character where you want it.

Comment: You're right. Your query runs fine, but Dbeaver ignores the new line in the column-headers that are displayed in dbeaver. Fortunately, however, the new line is NOT ignored once I export the result-set from Dbeaver to a cvs file.

Comment: Do you know of a way of doing a new line within those quotes without actually doing a line break in the SQL formatting?

Comment: Like I said, that depends on the client entirely. Column aliases are identifiers, so DB2 itself is not going to do any interpretation or interpolation.